Question about lemma 6.1 II in Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry book
In the proof of lemma 6.1 II in Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry book (see here for more details Question on Hartshorne II.6.1) he claims that there exists an open affine subset of $U = Spec\:A\subseteq X$ on which $f$ is regular i.e. $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$.
Why this open affine space exists?
Or maybe the more correct statement is that there exists such $U = Spec\:A\subseteq X$ on which $f$ is not necceraly regular on, but which have an open subset $V\subseteq U$ on which $f$ is regular on and that doesn't change the proof?

The ‘more correct statement’ implies the claim.

@Daniel For what ring $V$ is the spectrum?

$V$ contains an affine open set.

@Daniel which? can you write explicitly?

Affine opens are a basis for the topology on a scheme. I think this question is an abstract duplicate of this post.

Ok thank you @KReiser that answers my question.
